# SOAP PHP request error

Tags: php, api, soap, soap-client

I'm using a 3rd party api to request balances. I'm getting numerous errors on different tries but I know I'm close. here's my code for the call...

```
<?php 
try {   
$wsdl_url = 'https://www.domain.com/SOAP?wsdl';
$UserID = 'UserID';
$Pwd= 'Password';
$client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url);
$headerbody = array( 
                     'UsernameToken'=>array('Username'=>$UserID, 
                                             'Password'=>$Pwd)); 

//Create Soap Header.        
$header = new SOAPHeader('wsse', 'Security', $headerbody);        

//set the Headers of Soap Client. 
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header); 
//$client->__getLastResponse();
$BalanceInquiryRequest->AccountNo="7777700020";
$BalanceInquiryRequest->RetailerId="0123";

$getBalance = $client->balanceInquiry($BalanceInquiryRequest);
print_r($getBalance); 
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
echo $fault->faultcode . "-" . $fault->faultstring;  
//echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";
}

?>
```

the output of this is...

env:Server-java.lang.NullPointerException

and here's the xml for the request...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:req="http://domain.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">5Ht+O9hKvAEXhNJZSTLg==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2012-03-27T15:31:01.792Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <req:BalanceInquiryRequest>
         <req:AccountNo>7777700020</req:AccountNo>
         <req:RetailerId>0123</req:RetailerId>
      </req:BalanceInquiryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: The error is a Java error, which means the code is failing on the server side.  Do you have a way to debug the server side?  It could be any number of things, such as a parameter you are missing that you're supposed to pass, or a bug in the SOAP API source code that the original developer needs to fix, or a request for an invalid account number that the SOAP API does not handle correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this is a 3rd party API so I have no access. Also I tested this in SOAPUI and it works well, so it's def something I'm doing wrong. The account number is wrong but it should give me a XML based error response.

Comment: Can you try a tool like Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and compare the requests made by SOAPUI to the requests made by PHP?

Comment: Using charles, SOAPUI's request just gives me a bunch of jumbled encoded nonsense. Does my code look correct? or are you not sure?

Comment: The code looks ok to me.  You should be getting a more meaningful error message from the server if you have a problem in your request.  However, I've had experience in the past trying to integrate WS-Security between different programming languages is a nightmare, and we eventually dropped it with our Java<->ASP.Net interop.  Regarding the jumbled encoded nonsense, that's because of the HTTPS.  In Fiddler, there's an option to turn on HTTPS decoding which will show the actual request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, the issue was that the WSSE in my code is a standard that doesn't play nice with PHP SOAPClient. I did a bit of research and discovered that there's a few methods to make these two play together nicely. What I did was to first determine the name space, username and password...

```
$username = 'USERNAME';
$password = 'PASSWORD';

$strWSSENS = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
```

Next is to create two classes which process this info(found help online)...

```
class clsWSSEAuth {
  private $Username;
  private $Password; 
    function __construct($username, $password) {
      $this->Username=$username;
      $this->Password=$password;
    }
}

class clsWSSEToken {
  private $UsernameToken;
    function __construct ($innerVal){
      $this->UsernameToken = $innerVal;
    }
}
```

then call these few functions to set headers etc...

```
  $objWSSEAuth = new clsWSSEAuth($objSoapVarUser, $objSoapVarPass);
  $objSoapVarWSSEAuth = new SoapVar($objWSSEAuth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $strWSSENS, 'UsernameToken', $strWSSENS);
  $objWSSEToken = new clsWSSEToken($objSoapVarWSSEAuth);
  $objSoapVarWSSEToken = new SoapVar($objWSSEToken, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $strWSSENS, 'UsernameToken', $strWSSENS);
  $objSoapVarHeaderVal=new SoapVar($objSoapVarWSSEToken, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $strWSSENS, 'Security', $strWSSENS);
  $objSoapVarWSSEHeader = new SoapHeader($strWSSENS, 'Security', $objSoapVarHeaderVal,true, 'http://abce.com');
```

Then the rest is business as usual... with the SOAPClient...

Comment: ok great, and how to define this attribute on the password tag:  Type=”http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText”? And don't tell me just using an array with `_` key 'cause it does not work.